# Is ZnO still diamagnetic after you dope it with aluminium?

Tags: materials, magnetism

There are no unpaired electrons in $\ce{ZnO}$, making $\ce{ZnO}$ diamagnetic.

Aluminium has an unpaired electron, which would mean it is paramagnetic.

**Will $\ce{ZnO}$ become paramagnetic after it is doped with aluminium?**